# 802.1x EAP-TLS certificates protection

Tags: ieee-802.1x

I am trying to configure the network in my small office so that only specific devices can connect to the Ethernet ports. I have read that it is best to use 802.1x and EAP-TLS as the most secure method. I am trying to configure this with freeRADIUS on pfSense and with Mikrotik switches.

I just don't see how to solve the problem of the end user copying the certificate to a different computer than the one I want him to use. How to do something like this?

EDIT: on Windows client I see it is possible to use *.p12 file which requires a password to import into the system. As an administrator, I could do this import without giving the password to the user, but it looks like the certificate can be exported later. I don't know if the private key can be exported.

On Ubuntu, on the other hand, I don't know at all how to apply the *.p12 file. In the GUI you can only use *.crt and *.key files, so this private key file must simply be on the user's disk.

Comment: You can mark a certificate as non-exportable (only without private key) when installing user certificates - however, host configurations and issues are explicitly off-topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [sf].

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows you can install the certificate, and mark the private key as not exportable

Comment: Actually, when importing *.p12 file, the 'exportability' option of the key is disabled. So it looks like this is sufficient. Thanks!
If something like this could be done on Ubuntu it would be great.